# wxPython multithreading matplotlib plot NOT in the main thread

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

What I wanna do:

1. Run TCPServer in a thread
2. Get data "Receive from socket"
3. Update the plot and display the data

What I did successfully:

1. A frame with wxPython has a button,
2. click on the button start the socket
3. Receiving the data from the socket

The problem:

1. When i try to call the plotting function from the TCPServer thread, I receive this error

   ```
   "PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ..\..\src\common\timercmn.cpp(66)
   in wxTimerBase::Start(): timer can only be started from the main thread "
   ```

The Code:

1. Main, where I start the thread

   ```
   def start_socket(self):

       HOST = ''
       PORT_A = 6340
       self.server_A = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT_A), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
       self.server_temp = self.server_A
       self.server_A_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server_A.serve_forever)
       self.server_A_thread.setDaemon(True)
       self.server_A_thread.start()
   ```
2. The Thread, where I try to plot:

   ```
   class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
       def handle(self):
           self.Main =  Main(None, -1, '')
           self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
           print "%s wrote: " % self.client_address[0]
           print self.data
           plt.ion()    
           self.fig = plt.figure(1)
           print self.image_scale
           ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
           self.image_scale = ([1,2], [ 4,10 ] )
           cax = plt.imshow(self.image_scale, cmap='Greys', interpolation='nearest' )
           draw()
   ```

With debugging the Error comes from this line:

```
self.fig = plt.figure(1)

Error:  "timer can only be started from the main thread"
```

So, not sure, but I think I need to make the plotting in the main function of the wx.Frame,  Is there is any solution that allows keep the normal program running, and allow plotting in real time in another thread? Especially I intend to make more than one TCPServer thread.

Thank you in advance, your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i solved it, and running the timer from different threads now

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks anyway, i solved it, and running the timer from different threads now,

Its limitation in the language, with workaround it works

Comment: What is your workaround, can you show the solution details? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for share the solution... (ironic)